# Vue CLI 3 - problem with counting of inputs characters v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

i'm beginner in Vue and hope for your help :)

I need to count of characters in text inputs (but only numbers) has `v-model` and show the result as a some number variable. Inputs are inside elements displayed by `v-for` from `.json` file. Example code of my App.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="product-item" v-for="(product,index) in products" :key="product.id">
        <input type="text" v-model="coupon" @input='charCount()'>
        {{ couponCharCount }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    import productsData from "../public/products.json";
    
    name: 'App',
    data() {
        return {
            products: productsData,
            coupon: '',
            couponCharCount: 0
        }
    },
    methods: {
        charCount() {
            // only numbers filter
            this.coupon = this.coupon.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');

            // trying to count the characters
            this.couponCharCount = this.coupon.length;
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that when I enter some value, it fits in every `v-for` element `input`. What needs to be done to make it work separately for each `input`?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: what's the error that you are currently facing?

Comment: coupon should be on product or made into an array using the for loops index as its index to then do `{{charCount(product.coupon)}}` or `{{charCount(coupons[index])}}`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone can you show in my code what needs to be done? i changed `v-model` to  `v-model="coupons[index]"` and added to data `coupons: []` and now my method return nothing

Comment: @Amaarrockz, then when I enter a value into the `input` and try to calculate the number of characters using the method `charCount()`, the value is duplicated in all inputs

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain an array to manage all the input fields separately

````
<template>
    <div class="product-item" v-for="(product,index) in products" :key="product.id">
        <input type="text" v-model="coupon[index]" @input='charCount(index)'> <!-- Change added -->
        {{ couponCharCount[index] ? couponCharCount[index] : 0  }} <!-- Change added -->
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    import productsData from "../public/products.json";
    
    name: 'App',
    data() {
        return {
            products: productsData,
            coupon: [], // change added
            couponCharCount: [] // change added
        }
    },
    methods: {
        charCount(index) {
            // only numbers filter
            this.coupon[index] = this.coupon[index].replace(/[^0-9.]/g,''); // change added

            // trying to count the characters
            this.couponCharCount[index] = this.coupon.length; // change added
        }
    }
</script>```
````